# kotlin coroutine use inside a modified livedata <Boolean>. Running a counter and canceling it

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I need your help, there is a livedata that returns a Boolean value that is constantly changing. I need that when true the coroutine is executed (there is just an imitation of loading percentages from 0 to 100%), respectively, false cancels it, and so on in a circle.

if it returns true, ran the coroutine otherwise canceled it

```
graphicOverlay.onSuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        auraImageView.isInvisible = it != true
        noteScanFaceView.isVisible = it == false
        if (!isFaceDetected) {
            if (it) {
                buttonChangeCameraSelector.isVisible = false
                llScanning.isVisible = true
                viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {counter()}
                isFaceDetected = true
            } else {

             viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.cancel()
            }
        }
    })
```

this is a counter

```
private suspend fun counter() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val job = launch {
        while (progressStatus < 100) {
            progressStatus += 1
            delay(50)
            handler.post {
                textViewPercent.text = "$progressStatus"
            }
        }
    }
    job.join()
    fragmentSendDataListener.onSendResultsModel(resultSendData)
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
        llToolbar.isVisible = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do redefine your counter, you're launching a coroutine that launches a coroutine, which can be turned into just one coroutine launched. And in order to cancel a coroutine you have to make it **cooperatively cancellable**.

```
private suspend fun counter() {
    while (coroutineContext.isActive && progressStatus < 100) {
        progressStatus += 1
        delay(50)
        handler.post {
            textViewPercent.text = "$progressStatus"
        }
    }

    fragmentSendDataListener.onSendResultsModel(resultSendData)
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
        llToolbar.isVisible = false
    }
}
```

Since launch returns a job, keep a reference to it, and redefine/cancel it as
needed.

```
private var counterJob: Job? = null

graphicOverlay.onSuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        auraImageView.isInvisible = it != true
        noteScanFaceView.isVisible = it == false
        if (!isFaceDetected) {
            if (it) {
                buttonChangeCameraSelector.isVisible = false
                llScanning.isVisible = true
                counterJob = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {counter()}
                isFaceDetected = true
            } else counterJob?.cancel()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already done a bit of tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

[launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) returns a `Job`, which you can cancel instead of the whole coroutine scope.

So I'd do something as follows:

1. Save a reference to your counter job: `private var counterJob: Job? = null`
2. Update it when needed: `counterJob = launch { counter() }`
3. Cancel it when needed: `counterJob?.cancel()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work in my case. The coroutine is not canceled when false is received. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this case, the link is not zero, but the counter continues to go